# How to send different logstash event to different output

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

There are many events as fields that in logstash filter section are extracted from message field like below:

`match => ["message", "%{type1:f1} %{type2:f2} %{type3:f3}"]`

The purpose is to send f1, f2, f3 to one output and only f1 and f3 to other output plugin such that:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => "localhost"
        index =>"indx1-%{+YYYY-MM}"
        .
     }
 }
 output {
    elasticsearch {
       action => "index"
        hosts => "localhost"
        index =>"indx2-%{+YYYY-MM}"   
    }
  }
```

The problem is that all events are involved in every output pluggin but I want to handle which events goes to which output plugin.Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using filebeat to forward data to logstash. 
If running two instancea of filebeat and one instance of logstash, each filebeat forwarda input data to the same logstash but with different type like:

```
document_type: type1
```

In logstash, appropriate filter and output is exceuted using if clause:

```
filter {
   if [type] == "type1" {
   }
   else {
   }
 }
output {
  if [type] == "type1" {

    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM}"
    }

 }
 else {
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM}"

     }

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two distinct matching patterns in the "filter" section, then you can add specific "tags" for each match. Then in the output section use something like this:

```
if "matchtype1" in [tags] {
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "indxtype1-%{+YYYY.MM}"
    }
}
if "matchtype2" in [tags]{
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "indxtype2-%{+YYYY.MM}"
    }
}
```